# MySQL workbench couldn't show integer data type in GUI

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I go to see the table setting in Workbench GUI, it doesn't show the INT datatype, Query:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
staff_photo varchar(255),
staff_name varchar(50),
staff_surname varchar(50),
staff_email varchar(250),
staff_phone varchar(50),
staff_bio text,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

MySQL workbech version: 8.0.21 build 16448441 CE (64 bits) Community

MySQL workbench GUI:

[image]

Comment: which version are you using the last shows INT

Comment: @nbk version: 8.0.21 build 16448441 CE (64 bits) Community

Comment: close the window and use alter table again, it should show INT

Comment: Check why PK and AI are not checked in your Workbench id row.

Comment: @nbk doesn't worked.

Comment: there are several bugs in workbench,maybe it is ine if them, you should see if oraclw has already a bug report else make one